# Where do I get GTK+-3 from?

Tags: gtk, gedit

I want to compile the latest snapshot version of gedit on OSX as it has a lot of bug fixes and a number of new features, but I'm a little confused about the requirements to compile the sourcecode.

The readme says I need the GTK+-3 libraries, but for the life of me I can't seem to find them. I've gone through the GTK site, but there is only the 2.0 series available. Google doesn't seem to show any results for the 3.0 series either.

Anyone know how/where to get them?

The readme: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/README

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK 3 has not actually been released yet, it's the current "in-development" version for the upcoming release of Gnome 3. It's still in development and not at all ready for mainstream use.

Still, if you really insist on trying it out, you can get a source tarball from the [Gnome FTP server](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gtk+/2.99/).

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ 3 has been released some time ago (10-Feb-2001):

Sources: http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gtk+/3.0/

Git repo: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+